# Dialogflow V2 pushing information from Google Home to the Assistant App without a webhook

Tags: dialogflow-es

How can I send information to user's smartphone based on user's request on Google Home.

Use Case:
1.  User is looking for the highest grossing movie this weekend on Google Home by invoking "Top Grossing Movies"
2.  Google Home provides the name of the movie e.g. "Crazy Rich Indians"
3.  Then Google Home offers to send the link to the movie site so that user can learn more about it.
4. Ideal Scenario - User gets the link on their device.

How can the link be pushed to the assistant app on user's Android or iPhone when the conversation is happening on a Google Home device?

update:
After going through the documentation for google cloud, I came across the following link.
https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/surface-capabilities#nodejs

However, it doesn't explain how to switch a surface to push the rich card if there is no webhook.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the surface capabilities check to let the user know they should switch to a different device. You can see a demo of this in the [rich responses](https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-conversation-components-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js) sample using the Actions on Google Node.js library for building Actions on the Google Assistant.

The [Actions on Google docs](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/surface-capabilities#multi-surface_conversations) outline how to facilitating the handoff to a new device.

[image]

Then the following request will need to have an intent that is triggered by an `actions.intent.NEW_SURFACE` event.

[image]